# lighttpd conditional rewrite

Tags: linux, url-rewriting, lighttpd

Initially i wanted to add trailing / in my url (lighttpd)

which is possible to do with

```
    url.redirect = ( "^(.*[^/])$" => "$1/" )
```

Now i need to exclude some extensions like .txt, png etc. I want to add trailing slash for everything except those extensions, i dont seem to get that working.

In apache I could have used conditional rewrite, how would you do that in lighttpd.

Any directions would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make it together this would work (tested)

```
       $HTTP["url"] !~ "^(.*)(\..{3}|/)$" {
          url.redirect = (

           "^(.*[^/])$" => "$1/"
          )
        }
```

@david This would create never ending loop.....

```
 "^(.*)\.(png|txt)$" => "$1.$2",
    "^(.*[^/])$" => "$1/"
```

This will create ever lasting loop

@Matthew  This wont quite work as you are pushing everything to %1

```
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^(.*)(\..{3}|/)$" {
  url.redirect = (
    ".*" => "%1/" 
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much tike..that worked. thank you to david and matthew too.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple redirect rules:

```
url.redirect = (
    "^(.*)\.(png|txt)$" => "$1.$2",
    "^(.*[^/])$" => "$1/"
)
```

In this case, it will match everything with a literal `.png` or `.txt`, then try your original rule.

Comment: Actually I am looking for conditional rewrite, so that it does rewrite only if it is not png or txt ..

Comment: This is effectively a conditional redirect. The first rule that matches is the successful rule; in this case, the png/txt line gets rewritten into itself, and the redirect occurs. If that did not happen, it then tries the second redirect. Note this is a full redirect, not a soft rewrite.

Comment: Wouldn't "^(.*)\.(png|txt)$" => "$1.$2" cause a redirect loop or does lighttpd notices and ignores?

Answer (score 0):

```
$HTTP["url"] !~ "^(.*)(\..{3}|/)$" {
  url.redirect = (
    ".*" => "%1/" 
  )
}
```